# minify one of the files from the raw bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a configuration to bundle all **raw vanilla js** files

Copying/Dumping selective js code/files for 3 kinds of files.

1. mylib.js
2. mylib.min.js (same files as mylib.js + minify)
3. mylib-test.js (test scripts)

### Issues:

1. Unable to minify the min.js version, the output file is non-minified.
2. Ending up with a file named "main" in the bin directory.
3. If there's a better way of doing these things, lateral thinking?

---

Here's the webpack configuration.

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const RawBundlerPlugin = require("webpack-raw-bundler");
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: ["./index.js"],
    output: {
        filename: "[name]",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "bin")
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                include: /mylib-2.0.0.min\.js$/,
            }),
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.txt$/, use: "raw-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new RawBundlerPlugin({
            readEncoding: "utf-8",
            bundles: [ "mylib-2.0.0.js", "mylib-2.0.0.min.js", "mylib-2.0.0.test.js" ],
            "mylib-2.0.0.js": [
                "src/header.txt",
                "src/foo/Foo.js",
                "src/bar/Bar.js",
                "src/footer.txt"
            ],
            "mylib-2.0.0.min.js": [
                "src/header.txt",
                "src/foo/Foo.js",
                "src/bar/Bar.js",
                "src/footer.txt"
            ],
            "mylib-2.0.0.test.js": [
                "test/header.txt",
                "test/foo/FooTest.js",
                "test/bar/BarTest.js"
            ]
        })
    ],
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    }
};
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure the `include` property for TerserPlugin is the input files, not the output.

Comment: I'm kind of new to webpack, can you please explain what needs to be changed?

Comment: In the options for `TerserPlugin`, you're including `mylib-2.0.0.min.js` as the input, but that is in reality your output file. Also, instead of hard coding your version into your file names you can import it from `package.json`.

Comment: from package.json, didn't know that. Can you please post a solution code to the problem.

Comment: You can `import package from "./package.json"` and get the version number from there.

Comment: thanks, I tried that and i had substitution problem, how do you extract the variable ${package.version} with ticks before and after?